# How to create a vertical line before a paragraph?

Tags: vertical-alignment, rules

I want to make a formatting like the following in my document: 

`| Remark:
| This is my remark.`

I made an environment to encapsulate the remarks but i do not manage to create a vertical line that have the same height as the remark paragraph.

Everything I tried so far (multicol, minipage...) make some weird things like the misalignement of paragraph and the line or an oversized line.

Do someone has an idea?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
\newenvironment{dcremark}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}%
\color{dcblue}\noindent\textbf{Remarque :}%
}%
{%
\end{minipage}\\}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use `tcolorbox`. But we would appreciate the code with which  you managed to produce remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) you can say something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\newtcolorbox{tcbremark}{
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  oversize,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  bottomrule=0pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  title={Remarque :},
  title style={white},
  fonttitle=\color{black}\bfseries,
  titlerule=0pt,
  bottomtitle=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  left=5pt,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{tcbremark}
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcbremark}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: messes up footnotes